# How to implement back button functionality in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell  How to implement  back button functionality in sencha

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigationview component.NavigationView auto add Back button on top toolbar and handles functionality of Back.

Answer (score 0):

```
config: {
    title:'Home',
    layout:'fit',
    items:[
        {
            xtype:'titlebar',
            title:'Home',
            docked:'top',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Logout',
                    align: 'right',
                    initialize: function () {
                        this.element.on({
                            tap: function () { Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.widget('home'));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
      }
    }
```

});